# Keep UITableView position fix when popover controller is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller

I have created an app with a `UISearchbar` and a `UITableView` inside a `UIPopoverController`. Whenever I perform a search, the table correctly shows the right position needed, but when i dismiss the popover , automatically the current position and the selected cell is lost.
 So the situation is, I need when the popover is dismissed, and then re-called, to show me the exact position before the dismissal. My guesses are, when the popover is dismissed, the uitableview gets reloaded to starting position.
N.B. : The problem occurs when I perform the search using the search bar and dismiss the popover, If I don't use the search bar and just scroll down the table view, click on an item , dismiss the popover, and then re-open it, I will get the exact position I left it before dismissal.
This small sketch could help out more : 
[image]
Any ideas what I may be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that i needed to create a new mutable array that saves the newly filtered data. If the user searches an item, a boolean variable will change its value. In the view will appear method, a test on that boolean value will take place : If it had changed, the app will load the newly created mutable array, if not it will load the usual array. Hope this would help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand you're are saving `UITableview` position when you dismiss de popover and reloading it when the popover is called. If you perform a search the position of the `UITableview` change so if you save that position, when the *popover reloads it will go to a different place* because the search wasn't performed. 
What I think you should is. Save the search before you dismiss the popover. In viewDidLoad perform the search and then use the saved position of the `UITableview` to scroll to the right position.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply, can you please add some code snippets? to guide me throughout the process ?